# Finding negative numbers in Python CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, angle

I have a CSV file I'm reading with Northing and Easting values I'm trying to calculate the direction angle they are facing in...  have things mostly sorted out(I think) at this point, but the final values are all coming up between 0 and 90 it seems even though I have the following code in there...

```
   if (u_eastward >= 0) and (v_northward >= 0):
           azimouth = azimouth
   elif (u_eastward >= 0 and v_northward <= 0):
            azimouth = 180 - azimouth
   elif (u_eastward <= 0 and v_northward <= 0):
            azimouth = azimouth + 180
   elif (u_eastward <= 0 and v_northward >= 0):
            azimouth = 360 - azimouth
```

Azimouth is being calculated in Excel as '=ATAN(D2/C2)' to find radians and then being recalculated to the angle by '=DEGREES(E2)' on the arc tangent value which I think is correct.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can we see a sample of your data, that you expect to produce negative values? Also, your conditions overlap because you used <= and >= everywhere. Some of them need to be just < or >.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't properly converting my string to a float so everything was being seen as a positive value.